# Detach an anonymous EventHandler

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsubscribe anonymous method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp)
>   [How do I Unregister 'anonymous' event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348150/how-do-i-unregister-anonymous-event-handler)

Ok, lets say I have the following code:

```
    private void AttachEvent(AwesomeObject someObject)
    {
        int id = GetCurrentIdValue();
        someUnknownClass.SomeEvent += () => someObject.CreateAwesomeness(id);
    }
```

(essentially, I'm just trying to illustrate the need to use a local variable in an event handler as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488099/call-an-eventhandler-with-arguments)).  From a memory management standpoint, I can't just detach from someUnknownClass.SomeEvent because I don't have a handle on the handler.  Further, let's assume someUnknownClass is a third party type, so I can't add any code within that class to detach the event internally as suggested.

My question is, how do I avoid a memory leaks while still being able to use anonymous methods as event handlers?

Comment: As well as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348150/how-do-i-unregister-anonymous-event-handler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051357/c-sharp-adding-and-removing-anonymous-event-handler and many others.

Comment: Specifically with lambdas, answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1362244/1583

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, not in the way you use them. What you can do is assign that method to a variable and after use *that* variable to `+-` from event. But in this way you will loose "natural" feeling that closures usually give you .